# Library design practices that work while doing development in Microsoft .net technologies

Tags: .net, design-patterns, msdn

I was looking for a book or msdn article for developing a framework/library which extends the .net framework like [here](http://jolt.codeplex.com). Where can I find good design guidelines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The almost-canonical one is ["Design Guidelines for Developing Class Libraries"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229042.aspx), which is pretty much the online version of [this book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Framework-Design-Guidelines-Conventions-Development/dp/0321545613/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1288421496&sr=8-1). There's a lot of good information in there.

Answer (score 0):

Good book on framework design in .Net:

[http://www.amazon.com/Framework-Design-Guidelines-Conventions-Libraries/dp/0321545613](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321545613)